# Copy a block of matrix in to another block of matrix in OPENCV

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a matrix A, of $100x100$ elements.. I have another matrix  B with $50x50$ elements..

I want to copy a block of elements to  A, for example,

```
A(Range(10,30),Range(10,30))  = B (Range(5,25),Range(5,25));
```

The program is getting compiled and executed but the values are not getting copied. Any solution for this?

Comment: Really? A and B are objects, and that code compiles?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, it getting compiled

Comment: That's not your code. Either that, or A and B are not objects.

Comment: Anyways.. My main intention is to copy certain range of rows and cols of one matrix to another matrix. How can I do that?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore... actually the asker hasn't shown the complete code. From the look of the code, it seems that `A` and `B` are objects of `cv::Mat` class.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
cv::Mat A;
cv::Mat B;
cv::Mat C = A(cv::Range(10,30),cv::Range(10,30));
B (cv::Range(5,25),cv::Range(5,25)).copyTo(C);
```

I imagine what happens in your code is that your function call to A returns a Mat header which is then set equal to the Mat header returned by B.  By default, OpenCV does not copy cv::Mat data, you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @RavindraGadde glad to hear it!  If you find an answer useful on this site you can say thanks by accepting it if it is your own question (press the check mark) or upvote it if someone else asked the question (you need 15 rep to do that)